# Using only part of a pattern in SSH Config Hostname

Tags: unix, ssh, openssh

I have an SSH config like the one below, which works great for:

```
ssh b21
ssh 23
ssh s267
```

Example .ssh/config (hostname passed is slotted in at %h):

```
host s*
    HostName atrcu%h.example.com
    User example
    Port 22
host b*
    HostName atrcx%h.example.com
    User example
    Port 22
host ??*
    HostName atvts%h.example.com
    User example
    Port 2205
```

but I'd like to include the username in the host:

```
ssh b21ex
```

which would ssh to:

```
example@atvts21.example.com
```

but instead will:

```
atvts21ex.example.com
```

is their any way to cut/modify %h as it's passed and perhaps have the connection match more patterns to get a username along the way?

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you describe in the examples with the `match` specification instead of `host`. It's another way to specify a host, or a set of hosts.

For example:

```
Match user u* host t*
  Hostname %hest.dev
  User %r
```

This will match against a user pattern and a target host pattern.

The command line will then be something like `ssh u@t`, resulting in this substitution: `u@test.dev`.

Here's a snippet from the ssh debug output:

> ```
> debug2: checking match for 'user u* host t*' host t originally t
> debug3: /Users/_/.ssh/config line 2: matched 'user "u"' 
> debug3: /Users/_/.ssh/config line 2: matched 'host "t"' 
> debug2: match found
> ...
> debug1: Connecting to test.dev port 22.
> debug1: Connection established.
> ...
> u@test.dev's password:
> ```

`match` can match against a couple of other things (and there's an option to execute a shell command) but otherwise it's just like `host`. The ssh client options that go in there are the same ones (e.g. you can specify and `IdentityFile` that will be used with the matching spec)

You can read more in the man page:
[ssh_config](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config)

Comment: Interestingly enough, when this question was originally asked that feature didn't exist: https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-5.4/ssh_config

Comment: yep, I didn't know of it either, it's from 2014 apparently. I happen to check out the man page the other day for something else and found it. @RobC thanks for fixing my formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to create separate `HostName/User` entries for each possible abbreviation match. You could then use `%r` to access separate identity files for each user. This would allow you to skip using `user@host` for login at the expense of creating a more complex configuration file.

You might have better luck writing a script or shell alias that unmunges your abbreviations and hands them to `ssh` ready to go.